# Php pdo inserting 1 column into my database gives me error

Tags: php, sql

I have no idea why this code wouldn't work but when I run my code it goes instantly in the catch. I have been looking into and try multiple ways to insert it into my database but why can't I insert it? Is it because I only insert 1 value? My database table looks like this:

[image]

Here my code:

```
<?php
include "../includes/connection.php";
$ruimte_naam = $_POST['ruimte_naam'];

try{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO IA_Locatie (Ruimte_naam) VALUE (?)");
    $stmt->execute([$ruimte_naam]);

}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $stmt . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

Comment: Change `echo $stmt . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();`to `echo $e->getMessage();`

Comment: Alright now it gives me some other error that looks familar 
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'VALUE'.

Comment: try `VALUES` instead of `VALUE`

Comment: @Adder i would recommend you writing this as an actual answer

Comment: Yup correct, I knew it was something small and was already scared to ask it but couldnt figure it out! Thanks in advance

Comment: Ye i agree with @MarvinFischer, so others know I found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two steps to fix the problem:

Change `echo $stmt . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();`to `echo $e->getMessage();`

Use `VALUES` instead of `VALUE` so that it reads:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO IA_Locatie (Ruimte_naam) VALUES (?)");
```

Comment: better yet, get rid of that echo $e->getMessage(); and catch at all